Mercurial server on Ubuntu using Apache: error 403
I've had Mercuriual servers running on various Pis over the years, but need to set up a new machne and am struggling, what I think, is the final step in that I am getting:
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access this resource.
Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu) Server at 192.168.5.3 Port 80

When I try to access 192.168.5.3/hg from Firefox on my desktop machine. I can happily see http://192.168.5.3 and that serves up the default apache site.
This is on an RPi4 running Ubuntu whose fixed IP address is 192.168.5.3
I've followed these instructions, blended a little bit with what I have found has changed in recent years.
https://wiki.mercurial-scm.org/HgWebDirStepByStep
I have in /etc/apache2/hg a file called main.conf which contains this:
WSGIScriptAliasMatch ^/hg(.*) /var/hg/script/hgweb.wsgi$1
<Directory /var/hg/script>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>

In /etc/apache2/sites-available/ I have 000-default.conf which contains this:
    <VirtualHost *:80>
            # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
            # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
            # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
            # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
            # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
            # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
            # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
            #ServerName www.example.com
    
            ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
            DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    
            # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
            # error, crit, alert, emerg.
            # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
            # modules, e.g.
            #LogLevel info ssl:warn
    
            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    
            # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
            # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
            # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
            # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
            # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
            #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
            Include /etc/apache2/hg/main.conf
    </VirtualHost>
<Directory /var/hg/>
    Options +ExecCGI
    PassEnv LANG
    AddHandler hgweb .cgi
</Directory>
    
    # vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet

All I did to that existing file was add:
Include /etc/apache2/hg/main.conf & the <Directory /var/hg/> section

/var/hg/script/hgweb.wsgi contains this:
# An example WSGI for use with mod_wsgi, edit as necessary
# See https://mercurial-scm.org/wiki/modwsgi for more information

# Path to repo or hgweb config to serve (see 'hg help hgweb')
config = "/var/hg/hgweb.config"

# Uncomment and adjust if Mercurial is not installed system-wide
# (consult "installed modules" path from 'hg debuginstall'):
#import sys; sys.path.insert(0, "/path/to/python/lib")

# Uncomment to send python tracebacks to the browser if an error occurs:
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()

# enable demandloading to reduce startup time
from mercurial import demandimport; demandimport.enable()

from mercurial.hgweb import hgweb
application = hgweb(config)

This script was running on a Pi whose hard drive just died and was successfully serving my Mercurial files and I could push and pull no problem.
/var/hg/hgweb.config contains:
[paths]
bh0002 = /var/hg/bh0002
sam4sd32c_freertos=/var/hg/sam4sd32c_freertos
sqlforms=/var/hg/sqlforms
..snip..

With almost all of these files (other than
Logs are here:
tail -f /var/log/apache2/access.log
192.168.5.43 - - [06/Oct/2024:15:18:14 +0000] "GET /hg HTTP/1.1" 403 492 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:128.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/128.0"
192.168.5.43 - - [06/Oct/2024:15:25:16 +0000] "GET /hg HTTP/1.1" 403 493 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:128.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/128.0"
192.168.5.43 - - [06/Oct/2024:15:25:18 +0000] "GET /hg HTTP/1.1" 403 492 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:128.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/128.0"
192.168.5.43 - - [06/Oct/2024:15:25:23 +0000] "GET /hg HTTP/1.1" 403 492 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:128.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/128.0"
192.168.5.43 - - [06/Oct/2024:15:30:41 +0000] "GET /hg HTTP/1.1" 403 493 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:128.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/128.0"
192.168.5.43 - - [06/Oct/2024:15:30:43 +0000] "GET /hg HTTP/1.1" 403 492 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:128.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/128.0"
192.168.5.43 - - [06/Oct/2024:15:49:45 +0000] "GET /hg HTTP/1.1" 403 493 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:128.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/128.0"
192.168.5.43 - - [06/Oct/2024:16:34:04 +0000] "GET /hg HTTP/1.1" 403 493 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:128.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/128.0"
192.168.5.43 - - [06/Oct/2024:16:44:15 +0000] "GET /hg HTTP/1.1" 403 493 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:128.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/128.0"
192.168.5.43 - - [06/Oct/2024:16:44:16 +0000] "GET /hg HTTP/1.1" 403 492 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:128.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/128.0"

Is anyone able to suggest what step I have missed out or what might be different on this more modern version of Ubuntu maybe? If there is more information that will help, please let me know and I'll supply. As far as I can tell I'm using the same config files as on the old hard drive that had a failure. I was able to pull them off, despite it being corrupted and no longer able to boot, using a USB to sata interface.

Finally found as I'm on Apache 2.4 I now need:
In /etc/apache2/hg/main.conf
WSGIScriptAliasMatch ^/hg(.*) /var/hg/script/hgweb.wsgi$1
<Directory /var/hg/script>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

On to the next error...
